# How do I extract the "pattern" word when using Like operator?

Tags: vb.net

Hi i'm trying to figure out a way to retrieve a word from the like operator.
Ex:

```
    text = "jsoihj a125847 asf"
    Dim s as String = text Like "*a######*"
```

I would like 's' to equal the actual word that has the pattern of " * a###### * " instead of it returning True

Comment: you won't be able to do it with just `Like` alone... would be easy to do with regex though. also what happens if there is more than one word that satisfies the pattern?

Comment: As already mentioned you cant with just the `Like`. That operator returns a `Boolean` in which you cant change. There are other ways to do it, many other ways in fact...

Comment: `Like` operator return value of type `Boolean` - so you need to use some other approaches

Comment: Thanks guys, it took me like a min to figure out a way to retrieve it. Guess my mind was just dead on Friday

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the above comments Like will not give you the string.  You could parse the string character by character to find the pattern but this is a natural job for Regex.  I am no expert here so I use sites like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to hack out and test the match string.

```
dim s as string = Regex.Match(text, "([A][0-9])\w+").Value
```